# Is it possible to integrate Cortana to custom app as it is done in Edge?

Tags: uwp, cortana

I need integrate Cortana to my UWP application. But the application works in Kiosk Mode. I need integrate Cortana to the app like this is done in Edge - like park of application:

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: It's impossible, but you could tell us why you want to integrate Cortana in your app. There might be another way to achieve your final requirement.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Thank you. Our company develop industrial device. We use UWP app in kiosk mode for it UI. And we need voice control for this device. What another way to achieve this?

Comment: What did you need to do with voice control?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT This device tests oil quality. We need start test by voice command, like "Start new test with name Test1", or pause/stop running test.

Comment: Does the [Speech recognition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/speech-recognition) meet your requirement?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I did not found any info about how this works in Kiosk Mode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183172/discussion-between-fiftin-and-xavier-xie-msft).

Comment: If `Speech recognition` APIs don't meet your requirement, there's no other APIs for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Xavier Xie - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782612/xavier-xie-msft) for his answer:

If Speech recognition APIs don't meet your requirement, there's no other APIs for you.